# Is there a way to shorten repetitive math

Tags: c#

I have a math equation that is repeated for multiple variable but each time only the output and 1 variable is changed

```
R1S2NCtxt.Text = ((((ATT * R1S2) - EDEF) * 0.8M) + ((ATT * Pierce) - EDEF * ERES)).ToString();
R2S2NCtxt.Text = ((((ATT * R2S2) - EDEF) * 0.8M) + ((ATT * Pierce) - EDEF * ERES)).ToString();
R3S2NCtxt.Text = ((((ATT * R3S2) - EDEF) * 0.8M) + ((ATT * Pierce) - (EDEF * ERES))).ToString();
```

This is repeated multiple times is there a way to shorten this or repeat formula with different variables thx

Comment: This question isn't about the Visual Studio application so I've removed the `[visual-studio]` tag from your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a function to get rid of copy pasting code.

**Example:**

```cs
private string Calculate(float number) {
    return  ((((ATT * number) - EDEF) * 0.8M) + ((ATT * Pierce) - EDEF * ERES)).ToString();
}
```

**Now you can call that function with:**

```cs
R1S2NCtxt.Text = Calculate(R1S2);
R2S2NCtxt.Text = Calculate(R2S2);
R3S2NCtxt.Text = Calculate(R3S2);
```

Comment: Personally I would let `Calculate` perform the raw calculation and let the caller convert the result to a string if required.

Answer (score 2):

```
decimal Equation(decimal value)
    => (((ATT * value) - EDEF) * 0.8M) + ((ATT * Pierce) - EDEF * ERES);
```

Then:

```
R1S2NCtxt.Text = Equation(R1S2).ToString();
```

Assuming `R1S2` is `decimal`; if not then just amend the type of `value` accordingly.